# How can i color this shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

i tried a lot to color this shape to blue but couldn't . i'm using Photoshop but with tool Magic Wand .. is there any other way to color it please

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator is not especially flexible in editing bitmap images. I guess your image is a PNG which is one popular bitmap image format. Hopefully you have a higher resolution or at least a less blurred version (see NOTE1). If it's your photo, you hopefully can shoot a better version.

To edit bitmap images use Use Photoshop:

[image]

Use Image > Adjustment > Hue/Saturation. By setting option Colorize ON you get a strictly single hue result like above. If Colorize is OFF you get hue shift, but keep hue variations. RGB system limitations keep black and white uncolored.  If you expect color also for ex. to the white areas you should use adjustment layers. An example:

[image]

The curves layer (shown) is adjusted for acceptable contrast, but still so that the brightest white is now only grey. The Hue/Saturation layer makes the same as the adjustment Hue/Saturation above.

With Adjustment layes one can experiment without changing the underlying image permanently.

Such Photoshop things as layer masks and layer styles are as essential as adjustment layers in non-destructive editing. This example used only adjustment layers.

NOTE1: The image is blurry. Using Photoshop's sharpening filters such as Unsharp Mask helps a little:

[image]

Not asked, but you may want to make from scratch a sharp version. The Image is complex, I wouldn't try to make it in Photoshop nor Illustrator. In a 3D program the job is easy - at least, if one accepts a version where the holes are regular cones, like this:

[image]

The shape in the question is more difficult, because the less regular holes need much more tinkering than regular ones.

Comment: Op erroneusly tagged this illustrator.

Comment: It was not an error. OP was ready to see If Illustrator could  be used. Removing that tag is a way to get some kicks.

Comment: Ok, anyway you could do this in illustrator if you had some of the astute graphics plugins.

Comment: Illustrator  could be used as is .Blending modes change colors. But It is not handy.

Comment: Sure but astute has the hue transform. Anyway prefer to use smart sharpen instead of unsharp mask (unsharp mask is a signal conditioning tool from a time when we didnt know how to truly sharpen a signal)